# Nomenclature for methods, functions, and values

Tags: discussion, terminology

JavaScript (and other languages too) has long documentation names for commonly used methods. For example, the title of the MDN article for the `splice()` method on arrays is [`Array.prototype.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice). However, there is inconsistency on how methods are referred to in answers and questions. [This highly upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5767357/13376511) refers to `Array.prototype.splice()` as just `splice`. From the context, readers can figure out it is a function and a method of arrays, but it isn't represented in the name itself.

This isn't the only flavor of referring to methods and values. For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178325/how-do-i-check-if-an-element-is-hidden-in-jquery) adds dots in front of the method name, like `.hide()`, `.show()`, and `.toggle()`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39181977/13376511) refers to the value `String.prototype.length` as its full name. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/506004/13376511) even goes as far to use `window.location.replace(...)` (notice the ellipses inside the parentheses).

A little different from the prototype model, but still the same idea, is the prefix of `window.`. Looking through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage) question, some answers say `window.location.replace()`, some say `location.replace()`, and one even gives both versions.

All these examples have been in JS so far, but this can also be extended to languages with namespaces, like Rust and C++. For example, `std::cout` vs `cout`.

So, how much information should I convey about organization when referring to it in my question/answer text? Is it a free-for-all or should I lean towards one way? Also, should this be discussed on a per-language basis? I know that this is probably a hard question to answer, so is there any rule of thumb?

I feel like providing a full name like `Array.prototype.splice()` or `std::cout` is the most correct, but it could get unnecessarily long and possibly confusing to beginners who don't understand that `Array.prototype.splice()` means the `splice` method on an array.

Comment: Boah, no big deal I would think, no need to "overthink"... I also answer a lot about JavaScript (embedded in "some Command" for the Tag I Answer), I always use `splice()` / `split()` / `indexOf()` etc, but I wouldn't have any problem with sbd using `splice` / `split` / `indexOf`, the Backticks (Inline Code) make it clear it's a Command/Method...

Comment: Not sure it's a bit enough problem to need a rule for. I mean, sure - more uniformity would overall be better but I don't think lack of uniformity is really causing a problem. Usually when people say `slice` or `.slice()` it is clear the context is an array and method for it. Which `Array.prototype.slice()` also conveys. The notation I personally use is `Array#slice()` - the `#` denoting instance methods, as opposed to, say, `Array.from()` which is a static method. Again, though, I don't think the current usages really have an issue. Maybe edit unclear ones.

Comment: "*the prefix of window.. Looking through this question, some answers say window.location.replace(), some say location.replace(), and one even gives both versions.*" this seems like even less of a problem. Both `window.location` and `location` are the same. Literally one and the same thing. Being slightly more specific with `window.` doesn't really add much but it's also not an issue.

Answer (score 6):

> So, how much information should I convey about organization when referring to it in my question/answer text?

It's always a judgment call, there are no hard rules. See what fits your writing style best. The only advice I'd give is to link to the reference documentation the first time you mention the method call to make sure readers that want to learn more can do so.

Diving into opinions territory, a fully qualified name seems like the best option *the first time* a method is mentioned, then you can refer to it by its unqualified name for brevity.

On another note, I personally dislike the parenthesized (e.g., `methodName()`) naming convention as it is supposed to denote a method's *call* and use the "`methodName` method" convention instead.

> some answers say `window.location.replace()`

Regarding using `window`, the situation is a bit more complex. If it is obvious from the context that the [global object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Global_object) is a [`Window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window), qualifying global properties (such as `location`) with the `window.` prefix is fine. However, `window` is not the only possible global object: in workers, the global object is a [`WorkerGlobalScope`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope) that also has a [`location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/location) property — in this instance, using an unqualified name is the better option (as `WorkerGlobalScope` isn't accessed directly apart from the [`globalThis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis) property).